# Why BitBucket and GIT both need to run "clone"?

Tags: git, bitbucket

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50406477/826203
, to clone, there are two steps, first in BitBucket, then in GIT:

> On the  left side of bitbucket screen there is a vertical column with
> buttons. The second button from the top is "CLONE" button . Press on
> this button .You will get HTTP address .
>
> [image]
>
> Copy this address and use  in git in regular way  :
>
> `git clone <HTTP address of repo>`

I'm confused here, why clone has to be done twice?

My understanding is that, GIT is the client tool, BitBucket is the server side storing all repository info as Remote Repository. So isn't it that once "Clone" is run in client (GIT), the server side (BitBucket) shall clone accordingly?

Pls enlighten me, thanks.

Comment: Bitbucket isn't running clone. It's giving you the clone command to use.

Comment: oh! er.... why the command is named "Clone", shouldn't it be "url"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone a bitbucket repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996271/how-to-clone-a-bitbucket-repository)

Comment: @isherwood no. actually my question derives from the link you provided, from its 2nd answer

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a UI/UX question. You're not cloning anything in Bitbucket, you're choosing the button named after the thing you want to do. _"I would like to clone this repo,"_ says the user. **"Oh yes certainly,"** says Bitbucket, **"this is the information you need to do that."**

Comment: You've misinterpreted what you read in the other question. It actually explains it there. This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `git clone` command takes the repository in BitBucket and downloads it to your computer. BitBucket can't clone it by itself, so when you click the button you're just getting the address for `git` to download it from BitBucket.

Comment: then why the command is named "Clone", shouldn't it be "url"?

Comment: @athos maybe because it's shorter than "Get Clone URL" abd/or it's one of the steps to clone

Comment: Yes, "Clone" is simply shorthand for "Clone URL". It's sort of assumed that you'd understand that.